# Node.js - promise or callback for a Mongoose async findOne?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Among a number of other assignments in an express .post call, one .push is run in a forEach(function):

```
var toUsers = req.body.to; // [ 'user1', 'user2' ]
toUsers.forEach(toLoop);

function toLoop(element, index, array){

    Models.User.findOne({username: element},

        function (err, user) {

            toUserId = user._id;

            console.log('to: ' + element);
            console.log('toUserId: ' + toUserId);

            story.to.push({

                user : toUserId,
                username : element,
                updated : req.body.updated

            });

    });
}
```

This loop above is running after the .save call though!

```
story.save(function(err) {

    if (err)
        res.send(err);

    res.json({ message: 'Story Created' });

});
```

Comment: `findOne` is asynchronous!

Comment: @Bergi how would I write this as a callback or a promise?

Comment: Since it contains a loop, you should either use a callback library (like async.js, `async.map`) or promises (like Bluebird, `Promise.map`). Check their docs for examples and try it. If it doesn't work, [edit] your question to include your attempt.